# Filling and printing out an array of class type

Tags: c#

Okay, so I'm not very good with explaining, but basically i have a simple class - let's say something like this:

```
 class Dog
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Breed { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I have this other class:

```
static class DogData
{
    static public Dog[] Dogs 
    { 
        get
        {
            //Dog[] Dogs = new Dog[2]; - unnecessary, as pointed out by helpful Samaritans
            ResetDogData();
            return _dogs;
        }
        set { }
    }
    static public Dog[] _dogs;

    static private void ResetDogData()
    {

       Dog[] _dogs = new Dog[2];
       if (_dogs[0] == null)
        {
            _dogs[0] = new Dog();
            _dogs[0].Name = "Johny";
            _dogs[0].Breed = "German Shepard";
        }
        if (_dogs[1] == null)
        {
            _dogs[1] = new Dog();
            _dogs[1].Name = "Sally";
            _dogs[1].Breed = "Alaskan Malamute";
        }     
    }
```

The idea was to have the Dogs array being filled with input from the console, and if the array element
is null - to get its data from the ResetDogData(). But before trying to do this, i wanted to test
if the ResetDogData() even works.

And here's the thing - every time i try to print it out, i either get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' or, if it compiles, simply nothing prints out (depending on what way i tried doing it). So I was wondering if my code is totally wrong or I am simply missing some of the basics of working with arrays (e.g. my mistake is the way I am trying to print out the array).

I'd be really grateful if someone can tell me which of the two is it, and what is the right way to achieve what i want.

Comment: You initialize your Dog array with size 1 but then add 2 items. That can only fail. Furthermore, you probably do not want to re-create your Dog array everytime you call the getter of the property (because that can be costly and also because that not something anybody would expect from a property).

Comment: My guess is that you were trying to keep 0 based indexing in mind, but as @knittl mentioned, your array is too short. In C# consider using List<Dog> instead. Lists are dynamic and much easier to use.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I tried typing it out quickly, with few examples, and I didn't notice.

Comment: You can also cut down on lines of code by passing name and breed to your dog constructor

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that `DogData` should be `static` and that your `get` should recreate then discard a new `Dogs` array every time called. If you explained what you are trying to accomplish we may be able to better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResetDogData` is not modifying the class-level `_dogs` member - is it creating a local `_dogs` variable, populating it, and then doing nothing with it.

To reset the class member's data, change

```
Dog[] _dogs = new Dog[2];
```

to

```
_dogs = new Dog[2];
```

within `ResetDogData`

also, you can get rid of the `if`a, since the newly-created array will *always* be initialized with `null`:

```
static private void ResetDogData()
{

    _dogs = new Dog[2];

    _dogs[0] = new Dog();
    _dogs[0].Name = "Johny";
    _dogs[0].Breed = "German Shepard";

    _dogs[1] = new Dog();
    _dogs[1].Name = "Sally";
    _dogs[1].Breed = "Alaskan Malamute";

}
```

Comment: Thank you, now it resets it and I can print out the defaults. But if i may ask a follow up question - in my understanding, now every time, no matter if i populated **Dogs** or not, it would be replaced by the **_dogs** data. Is it correct to write something like this: `_dogs=Dogs;` instead, and then perform checks, to see if the array elements have a value, and if not - then give them the default one? Or would that cause for the **get** method of **Dogs** to be called again, and in return everything would crash?